# Fill blanks on the column based on the remaining two columns and data present on the blanks column

Tags: match, fuzzy

Am about to achieve filling blanks on a column, however the column has somedata. Now I wanted to impute rest of the data where there are blanks based on the available columns on the dataset.
Sample data is attached here, am looking for fuzzy approach to the query above.

Basically, I have a data of 5,00,000 rows in which there are 6,800 rows of blank.

Column C already have data, whereas it is left with 6800 blanks this needs to be filled based on the combination of column a and b not with d (Apologies) for the confusion.

If any of the combinations of column a and b had populated data in column c
and same combination is having blank on the 6800 rows that should be filled based on the above criteria.

```
 a                                b                     c
```

Pension ER A Sec         Pension ER A Sec 20%           605
Period Base Sal BT       Period Base Sal BT                 704
myShare Plan                 myShare Plan                   508
Transportation Allowance     Transportation Allowance           227
Hypo Tax (Salary)        Hypo Tax (Salary)                 1001
Amount paid              Amount paid                   1025
Car assistance               Car assistance - cash allowance    202
Hypo NI (Salary)         Hypo NI (Salary)                   908
Housing Allowance        Housing Allowance
Pens Supp Allwnce        Pens Supp Allwnce
Home Allowance               Home Allowance
Assignment Allowance GRS     Assignment Allowance GRS
Sal Supp Allowance GRS       Sal Supp Allowance GRS
Accident Ins                 Accident Ins
Relocation Allowance GRS     Relocation Allowance GRS
Bonus                        Bonus
Total                        Total
Sueldo                       Sueldo
RET. TAX INCOME              RET. TAX INCOME
Plus vacacional              Plus vacacional

I have tried imputing the values in the blank cells but unable to fill the blanks am looking for a fuzzy logic where this can fill gap on the missing values on column C based on the columns a and b

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.